# How to keep the PostgreSQL "System Administration/Information functions" from read-only users

Tags: sql, postgresql, permissions

In my case, a read-only user can perform the "System Administration/Information functions".

I tried to restrict those functions by hard-coding that in my code. But that cannot be a proper solution, since there can be new such functions in future releases of PostgreSQL, or functions may get renamed.

So I need to get those functions dynamically. Is there a way to determine which function belong to the "System Administration/Information functions", or how to restrict access to them for a read-only user?

Comment: You want a read-only user to be able to kill sessions, start backups, and read files on the database server? Interesting.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I want to restrict the read-only user from performing complex functions like pg_sleep and restrict them from killing sessions and initiating a backup.

Any ideas? @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: A regular user can only kill their own sessions, so there is no risk having that privilege. And none of the other functions pose any risks, so what problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: I have a server where a read-only user executes a db query after getting an input query from the user. Now if the input user gives a query that contains pg_sleep function and was able to put the db on-hold for any amount of time, it poses a threat to my app. To fix this, I have created a list of functions hard-coded in java to restrict them after getting user input. But what if pg creates some other function like pg_sleep which I need to avoid executing? I had to keep updating the list right? (1/2)

Comment: What I'm trying to do is restrict the System Administration/Information functions for read-only users dynamically. (2/2) @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Why not set a statement timeout to avoid long running queries?

Comment: Ok, then the problem is in your command of the English language. I'll try to fix the question.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to safely identify those functions other than enumerating them. But I think that your goal is wrong. A user who can execute SQL statements can *always* launch a denial-of-service attack. These functions are among the lesser problems. Never let a user you do not trust run SQL statements on your database.